# Font Awesome displayed as question marks ion macOS

Tags: macos, font, font-book

I downloaded `font-awesome-4.6.3.zip` from [fontawesome.io](http://fontawesome.io/). Double click `fontawesome-webfont.ttf` (under `font-awesome-4.6.3/fonts/`) to install the font, but I got this,

[image]

Comment: Same problem for me. Trying to use with Sketch. Only some icons work, most don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preview probably won't show anything because this font doesn't appear to have any normal Latin characters but consists of graphics located in the Private Use Area of Unicode.  See

http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/

You should certainly be able to install it.  To use it probably requires the Character Viewer. Others will never see it in your pages unless you set it up as a webfont which gets downloaded automatically when they view your page.

Comment: Thx, but some of them don't work, such as `fa-envelope`.

Comment: In general I would not rely on private use fonts always working, but you could check with the people who made it.  Envelope may also be a normal character ✉️

Comment: My problem is caused by office for MAC. Pages works perfectly.

Comment: Is that Office 2016?

Comment: Yes, version 15.19.1. One trick is to copy icon fonts from pages to office word.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the first answer, after installing, a way to see all the characters using Font Book is to change the view from "Sample" to "Repertoire". This will show you the actual glyphs available.

[image]